Grammar of 寒い風の吹くに任せて
From Kokoro chapter 24:

東京へ帰ってみると、松飾はいつか取り払われていた。町は寒い風の吹くに任せて、どこを見てもこれというほどの正月めいた景気はなかった。

I wonder how the grammar works in 寒い風の吹くに任せて. I wonder why it is possible to use の like that even though there's no relative clause and why に can be attached to 吹く. It seems to me that 寒い風の吹くに任せて means the same as 寒い風が吹くままに任せて.

There are many fixed expressions involving に which can follow the plain form of verbs, such as に違いない. Maybe this is a holdover from Classical Japanese? I am told that the rentaikei could be used as a noun. As for の, I agree that it seems to be a case of の・が conversion.

寒い風の吹くに任せて is a literary-sounding version of 寒い風の吹くのに任せて. In classical Japanese, nominalization was done by using the attributive form.

<動詞の辞書形>　+　がよい ―　How is this allowed?
Plain Verb followed by がよい

So 寒い風の吹く is a relative clause, and that's why の is used as the subject marker for 吹く.
